# How to Create a MicroService in .Net Core / Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, microservices

> This buzzword is making me pull my hair... I have been asked to create
>   a **microservice** using **.net core**.

Googled a lot, different definitions and samples, but still, I don't know what makes a vs project a microservice / how can I create a microservice in VS. For example, I have asked to create a microservice where a user will input two latitude and longitude values and they will get the distance between them.

---

Cool, I can do this as a web project in no time. But here I need this as a microservice where the rest of the projects in our firm can use it.
What really makes a VS project into a Microservice or can I convert a project into a micro service? Microservice experts are welcome ...!!! I looking for that step by process in which a microservice is created in .net core.

Comment: You'll probably want to use HTTP or a similar protocol, so just writing an webapi thing should be "ok". I'd say the real question is how you'll deploy any number of microservices once you have them designed/implemented. For this part, you're possibly looking at stuff like Kubernetes, Service Fabric (avoid), or a third container framework (maybe just straight docker). A fourth approach is not to use containers, but a thinner management layer (it's optional and depends on project size in the end, last approach is explained in this book: https://www.manning.com/books/microservices-in-net-core).

Comment: Try to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design which will give a blue print on how you can architecture you solution. Keep in mind that micro service architecture suggests that you use multiple databases for almost each functionalities you may have and a central configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a template for creating a microservice in .NET, because any application that is deployable in a standalone way and that is reachable over some form of communication protocol (be it HTTP, message queues, or anything else) to perform some sort of action can be called a microservice.

See also [Martin Fowler: Microservices](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) and [.NET microservices - Architecture e-book](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/microservices-architecture).

So to create your service that will *"[accept] two latitude and longitude values and [return] the distance"*, you can simply create an ASP.NET Core Web API with one action method, and that's your microservice.

Comment: Ohhkkk ... Let me try it first. quick response... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A microservice is simply a concept. You won't find a "Microservice" template in Visual Studio. Generally, you're going to be implementing a REST API. A microservice doesn't *have* to be a REST API, but they most normally are.

You also generally won't just be making a microservice, but rather microservice*s*. One of the core tenants of a microservice is that it should deal with just one discrete unit of functionality. Unless your application does just one very boring thing, you'll need multiple microservices. For example, for an ecommerce site, you might have a user service, a cart services, a checkout service, an order service, etc.

To coordinate the efforts of all these microservices, it's also typical to implement an API gateway. The application will work with the gateway only, and the gateway will proxy out the requests to each individual microservice to get the information or do the work that the application requires. In a sense, it acts as a conductor would, coordinating all the individual instruments to create the harmony.

Long and short, most likely what you want is one or likely more ASP.NET Core API project(s). You'll create controllers and actions on those controllers, where the latter of which will effectively become your endpoints, i.e. the functional routes your API exposes to do work. Since a microservice architecture is desired, these API project(s) should remain small and razor-focused, potentially only each working with just one entity class or maybe a very narrow slice of app functionality that involves multiple entities. You should strive to keep them as lightweight as possible, minimizing the amount of middleware and external libraries involved. When it comes to deployment, it's most typical to use containerization - Docker is a popular choice for that.

Comment: Chris, just saw your comment here. Very helpful thanks. Thinking of creating an application with micro services. For the limitations of the client, I can only use the least number of tools possible. Is there any API gateway that comes with .net core? Can I deploy the solution/micro services without docker container? Please explain what are the minimum required tools to architect a microservices application using .net core.

Comment: Containers are preferred because they're light-weight, self-contained, and easily scalable. However, there's a myriad of ways to create and deploy microservices. It's paradigm, not some formulaic mix of tech.

Answer (score 0):

Another really good resources aside from what others have mentioned is: https://12factor.net/

It doesn't talk about any implementations (so you wont find references to .NET Core in there) but it does talk about how to design your application so it behaves more like a microservice - including dealing with scaling and processes that are stateless.

And to clarify a point of confusion: there's no special application type for a microservice. If your application behaves like a microservice, it is a microservice!